# Python: @property decorator infinite loop when initializing?

Tags: python

The Python version is `3.6.5.`. I'm learning how to correctly use the `@decorator` syntax sugar for my `class Duck`. But it seems like I did something wrong and my `qq_duck` died of overheating. Here is the demo:

```
class Duck(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        print("Quack! My name is", self.name)

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        print("I've decided to change my name into", name, ".")
        print("So please call me", name, "from now on! Quack!")
        self.name = name
```

Terminal:

```
qq_duck = Duck("QQ")
I've decided to change my name into QQ .
So please call me QQ from now on! Quack!
I've decided to change my name into QQ .
So please call me QQ from now on! Quack!
I've decided to change my name into QQ .
So please call me QQ from now on! Quack!
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 3, in __init__
  File "<input>", line 13, in name
  File "<input>", line 13, in name
  File "<input>", line 13, in name
  [Previous line repeated 488 more times]
  File "<input>", line 11, in name
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Please help...

Comment: `self.name = name` calls your setter function... from within the setter function.

Comment: You could easiliy avoid the recursion by storing the `name` variable in a `self._name` instead of `self.name`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the setter function calls itself when you assign `self.name = name`. this will indeed result in an infinite recursion.

the fix could be this:

```
class Duck(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

@property
def name(self):
    print("Quack! My name is", self._name)
    # here you usually return the data member...
    return self._name

@name.setter
def name(self, name):
    print("I've decided to change my name into", name, ".")
    print("So please call me", name, "from now on! Quack!")
    self._name = name
```

note how the member `self._name` is different from the property `self.name`.

Answer (score 1):

What your self.name does is calling your just defined property. But this is what it called in the first place, so it will loop infinitely.

This code could be represented as :

```
self.name = "something" + ("something" + ("something" + ...[on to infinity!]...) )
```